# Is it possible to have a Screwdriver pipeline hooked to a GitHub organization?

Tags: screwdriver-cd

- **Any PR/push on any repository in this organization MUST trigger the Screwdriver pipeline.**
- This Screwdriver pipeline will be in charge to check all the repositories in this organization to be compliant to some internal rules/policies.

Is it possible to do that with Screwdriver?

Thanks,

Ref: http://screwdriver.cd/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, When you create a build pipeline Screwdriver automatically adds a webhook to the underlying Git repository. This webhook allows Screwdriver to automatically start build workflow on PRs or commits or even on tags and releases.